I1 writing back to memory, while I2 currently executing on value depended on I1. How is result coherency maintained?
question regarding OOE.
Imagine two instructions
mov %rax, [an_address} // I1
mov [an_address] %rbx  // I2

I1 makes it into the execute stage of an intel CPU. And imagine the execute unit is full now, so it's put into a reservation station. Then I2 also goes into that RS. Now I1 eventually gets to executing, after that heres the issue part

I1 moves to memory stage
I2 moves to execution unit. I2 depends on the memory data of I1, but I1 rn is updating memory as we speak.

So how does this get fixed in cpus?
Does I1 hold up I2 from being executed until I1 is commited?
Or better question, how does the cpu make sure l2 uses the new value stored in the memory address which was created by l1?

I think that the "memory stage" belongs to in-order cpus.
With OoOE, both load and store operations when they are "executed" by the back-end just put entries into Load and Store Queues, correspondingly. And these queues make sure that memory operations accessing the same address, are performed in the program order.
Once the load operation gets the actual data, they are placed into the ROB entry of this load operation, which is now ready to be retired.
